# regenerating matrix R

Tags: r, matrix

I have a script which generates a matrix using binomial function:

```
randomdiv <- function(ncells, ndivs, size) { sz <- matrix(nrow = ncells, ncol = ndivs) 
#avsz <- vector(length =ndivs) 
#sdsz <- vector(length =ndivs) 
#count <- vector(length = ndivs) 
#loss <- vector(length = ndivs) 
for (j in 1:ncells) {
n <- size
for (i in 1:ndivs)
{
n <- rbinom (1, n, 0.5)
n <- 2 * n
sz[j,i] <- n
}
}
return (sz)
}

randomdiv(20,20, 20)
```

I need to generate this matrix 20 times, each time generating new values according to the pre-defined binomial function.

I had initially vectorised as such:

```
mean20 <- randomdiv(20, 20, 20)
```

But this labels a specific matrix as "mean20" so that if I run mean20 multiple times, identical matrices are produced - I need the script to be run fresh for each matrix.

Even without vectorising the inital matrix the following code does not tell R to regenerate the matrix each time - so rather than a matrix of column means for 20 matrices, this generates column means for one matrix and repeats them for 20 columns.

```
mean20 <- round(matrix(data=colMeans(randomdiv(20, 20, 20)), nrow=20, ncol=20))
```

Any ideas how I tell R that I want the column means of 20 matrices compiled into one matrix?

Thanks!

Comment: Please provide working code, a clear explanation of what you are trying to do and your desired output.

Comment: As noted, your code does not work. Or perhaps a more accurate description is that your write up is incomplete.

Comment: I thought I had included everything it needed to be functional sorry - I have edited it, and I think it should now work

Answer (score 5):

The OP uses the number `20` all over the place, so I may not have this quite correct:

```
res20 <- replicate(20, randomdiv(20,20,20), simplify=FALSE )
sapply(res20, colMeans)
```

To illustrate the result, here's a smaller example:

```
set.seed(1)
res4 <- replicate(10, randomdiv(4,4,4), simplify=FALSE )
sapply(res4, colMeans)

#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
# [1,]  2.5  4.5  4.0  4.0  5.0  5.0  2.5  4.5    5   2.5
# [2,]  1.5  5.5  5.5  4.5  4.5  5.5  2.5  4.5    4   4.0
# [3,]  2.5  5.0  3.5  5.0  3.5  5.5  3.5  3.5    4   4.0
# [4,]  3.5  5.0  4.5  3.5  3.5  6.5  4.0  4.5    3   4.0
```